# Obtaining next scheduled run time of a DAG using Airflow 2.2.5 REST API

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, airflow, airflow-api

I used Airflow 2.4.2 REST API and python `apache-airflow-client` to retrieve the next scheduled run time of a DAG.

```py
from airflow_client.client.api import dag_api


 with airflow_client.client.ApiClient(conf) as api_client:
        api_instance = dag_api.DAGApi(api_client)
        dag_id = build_dag_id(name)

        response = api_instance.get_dag(dag_id)
        next_run = response["next_dagrun"]
```

However, now I need to do the same with Airflow 2.2.5 REST API, and it turns out that the `next_dagrun` value does not exist there. Now I'm looking for an alternative way to obtain this value. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if you have a datetime of the last run, you can use this approach:

```
# Obtain the DAG's schedule interval    
url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/{dag_id}'
response = requests.get(url)
dag_info = response.json()
schedule_interval = dag_info['schedule_interval']

# Calculate the next scheduled run time
last_run = datetime.now()
cron = croniter(schedule_interval, last_run)
next_run = cron.get_next(datetime)
```